# Creating Sugar configuration file (config.php) Creating Sugar application tables, audit tables and relationship metadata

Tags: xampp, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am getting timeout error and tried everything to change its value from 600 but now luck. Can any body help to do this for SugarCRM?

Comment: did you try with ini_set?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing in SugarCRM configuration file config.php try to change in config_override.php. You can also add your custom configuration using module loader apply following code in manifest.php file.

```
$cfg = new Configurator();
   // Your custom configuration code 
    $cfg->config['myaddon_setting'] = true; // This will make add-ons setting enable. 
    $cfg->handleOverride();
```

To Perform database queries use following code.

```
    $mymodule = BeanFactory::newBean($module); 
    $db = DBManagerFactory::getInstance();  
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1";  
    $result = $db->query($query, true,"Error reading the database");
```

For logic hooks click on [Logic Hooks](http://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_7.8/Architecture/Logic_Hooks/). Write down in comment if you need anything else.